# Wix bootstrapper won't detect installed .NET framework

Tags: .net, wix, version, bootstrapper

I have a Wix installer and bootstrapper application to install my application and a service. As a prerequisite I need the .NET 2.0 SP2 Framework installed and tried to detect that using the following codesnippet:

```
    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id='Netfx2Package' />
      <MsiPackage SourceFile="..\Wix.CHL7.Dispatcher.Service.AZHF\bin\Debug\Wix.CHL7.Dispatcher.Service.AZHF.msi" Id="Wix.CHL7.Dispatcher.Service.AZHF_PackageId" Cache="yes" Visible="no">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLDIR" Value="[INSTALLPATH]" />
        <MsiProperty Name="WixAppFolder" Value="[INSTALLSCOPE]"/>

      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>

  <Fragment>
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="Netfx2Package" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="NetfxLicense.rtf" />      

    <PackageGroup Id="Netfx2Package">
      <ExePackage Id="Netfx2Exe"
                  Cache="no"
                  Compressed="no"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  Vital="yes"
                  SourceFile="C:\Installation\Wix.CHL7.Dispatcher.Service.Bootstrapper\lib\NetFx20SP2_x86.exe"
                  DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/6/e/c6e88215-0178-4c6c-b5f3-158ff77b1f38/NetFx20SP2_x86.exe"
                  DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK20"
                  InstallCondition="FALSE"/>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

When I run the installer on a machine which has .NET 2.0 SP2 installed (checked that in the registry) my installer wants to download and install the framework.

I assume my DetectCondition is incorrect but can't seem to find a correct solution to my problem.
So how do I detect if .NET 2.0 SP2 is installed in my bootstrapper?

Thanks in advance!

W

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are referencing the NetFxExtension properly.

Source: [WixNetfxExtension](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wixnetfxextension.htm)

> Using WixNetfxExtension Properties To use the WixNetfxExtension
>   properties in an MSI, use the following steps:
>
> Add PropertyRef elements for items listed above that you want to use
>   in your MSI. Add the -ext  command line
>   parameter when calling light.exe to include the WixNetfxExtension in
>   the MSI linking process.
>
> For example:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK20" />
```

Also, you probably want to use the property `NETFRAMEWORK20_SP_LEVEL` to get the appropriate service pack level if you require SP2. When troubleshooting I'd also check the install log to see if it indicates what the property values are set to.